# Camel filter didn't work

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to transfer file through sftp config. But don't know why camel filter is not working. I am using camel 2.17.3 and jdk 1.7

I don't know how to solve it.
If you have any kind of thoughts please share.Thanks in advance

## In my applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans default-autowire="byName"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring-2.17.3.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">


<bean id="myFilter" class="in.client.camelbean.MyFileFilter"/>

<import resource="actionRoutes.xml" />

    <camelContext streamCache="true"
        xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <package>in.client.camelbean</package>
        <routeContextRef ref="actionRoutes" />
    </camelContext> 

</beans>
```

## In my actionRoutes.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring-2.17.3.xsd ">

    <!-- Only the routeContext is here -->

    <routeContext id="actionRoutes" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <route id="route3">   
                <from uri="file:\\home\41\test\Respfiles?filter=#myFilter;delete=true"/>               
                <to uri="sftp://CFTEST@xxx.xxx.x.xx:20//Users/C.SRV1/SAMPLE/PAC?password=test123&amp;passiveMode=true&amp;noop=true"/>                         
            </route>

</routeContext>
</beans>
```

## In my java class

```
import org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFile;
import org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileFilter;


public class MyFileFilter<T> implements GenericFileFilter<T> {
    public boolean accept(GenericFile<T> file) {

        System.out.println("File...."+file.getAbsoluteFilePath() + " : " + file.getFileNameOnly());

        // we dont accept any files starting with temp in the name
        return !file.getFileName().startsWith("temp");
    }
}
```

## Now I am getting this error

```
     14:43:53,236 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-7) Context initialization failed: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route rout3: Route(route3)[[From[file:\\home\41\test\Respfiles?f... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: file://%5C%5Chome%5C41%5Ctest%5CRespfiles?filter=%23myFilter%3Bdelete%3Dtrue due to: Could not find a suitable setter for property: filter as there isn't a setter method with same type: java.lang.String nor type conversion possible: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileFilter with value #myFilter;delete=true
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1690) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:138) [camel-spring-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:340) [camel-spring-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:97) [org.springframework.context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:324) [org.springframework.context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:929) [org.springframework.context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467) [org.springframework.context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385) [org.springframework.web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284) [org.springframework.web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111) [org.springframework.web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route3: Route(route3)[[From[file:\\home\41\test\Respfiles?f... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: file://%5C%5Chome%5C41%5Ctest%5CRespfiles?filter=%23myFilter%3Bdelete%3Dtrue due to: Could not find a suitable setter for property: filter as there isn't a setter method with same type: java.lang.String nor type conversion possible: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileFilter with value #myFilter;delete=true
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:201) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:974) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:3301) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3024) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:175) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2854) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2850) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:2873) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:2850) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:2819) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.maybeStart(SpringCamelContext.java:270) [camel-spring-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:136) [camel-spring-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: file://%5C%5Chome%5C41%5Ctest%5CRespfiles?filter=%23myFilter%3Bdelete%3Dtrue due to: Could not find a suitable setter for property: filter as there isn't a setter method with same type: java.lang.String nor type conversion possible: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileFilter with value #myFilter;delete=true
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:588) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:79) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.resolveEndpoint(RouteDefinition.java:211) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:107) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:113) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.model.FromDefinition.resolveEndpoint(FromDefinition.java:69) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.getEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:89) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1052) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:196) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a suitable setter for property: filter as there isn't a setter method with same type: java.lang.String nor type conversion possible: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileFilter with value #myFilter;delete=true
    at org.apache.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport.setProperty(IntrospectionSupport.java:588) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport.setProperty(IntrospectionSupport.java:616) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport.setProperties(IntrospectionSupport.java:473) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport.setProperties(IntrospectionSupport.java:483) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.util.EndpointHelper.setProperties(EndpointHelper.java:255) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.setProperties(DefaultComponent.java:259) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileComponent.createEndpoint(GenericFileComponent.java:67) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileComponent.createEndpoint(GenericFileComponent.java:37) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(DefaultComponent.java:114) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:568) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    ... 36 more

14:43:53,261 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/WiseBank_EIP_Next]] (MSC service thread 1-7) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route3: Route(route3)[[From[file:\\home\41\test\Respfiles?f... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: file://%5C%5Chome%5C41%5Ctest%5CRespfiles?filter=%23myFilter%3Bdelete%3Dtrue due to: Could not find a suitable setter for property: filter as there isn't a setter method with same type: java.lang.String nor type conversion possible: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileFilter with value #myFilter;delete=true
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1690) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:138) [camel-spring-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:340) [camel-spring-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:97) [org.springframework.context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:324) [org.springframework.context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:929) [org.springframework.context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467) [org.springframework.context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385) [org.springframework.web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284) [org.springframework.web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111) [org.springframework.web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route3: Route(route3)[[From[file:\\home\41\test\Respfiles?f... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: file://%5C%5Chome%5C41%5Ctest%5CRespfiles?filter=%23myFilter%3Bdelete%3Dtrue due to: Could not find a suitable setter for property: filter as there isn't a setter method with same type: java.lang.String nor type conversion possible: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileFilter with value #myFilter;delete=true
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:201) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:974) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:3301) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3024) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:175) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2854) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2850) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:2873) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:2850) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:2819) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.maybeStart(SpringCamelContext.java:270) [camel-spring-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:136) [camel-spring-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: file://%5C%5Chome%5C41%5Ctest%5CRespfiles?filter=%23myFilter%3Bdelete%3Dtrue due to: Could not find a suitable setter for property: filter as there isn't a setter method with same type: java.lang.String nor type conversion possible: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileFilter with value #myFilter;delete=true
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:588) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:79) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.resolveEndpoint(RouteDefinition.java:211) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:107) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:113) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.model.FromDefinition.resolveEndpoint(FromDefinition.java:69) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.getEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:89) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1052) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:196) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a suitable setter for property: filter as there isn't a setter method with same type: java.lang.String nor type conversion possible: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileFilter with value #myFilter;delete=true
    at org.apache.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport.setProperty(IntrospectionSupport.java:588) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport.setProperty(IntrospectionSupport.java:616) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport.setProperties(IntrospectionSupport.java:473) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.util.IntrospectionSupport.setProperties(IntrospectionSupport.java:483) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.util.EndpointHelper.setProperties(EndpointHelper.java:255) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.setProperties(DefaultComponent.java:259) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileComponent.createEndpoint(GenericFileComponent.java:67) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileComponent.createEndpoint(GenericFileComponent.java:37) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(DefaultComponent.java:114) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:568) [camel-core-2.17.3.jar:2.17.3]
    ... 36 more

14:43:53,586 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiInjectorFactory] (MSC service thread 1-7) Found BeanManager at java:comp/BeanManager
14:43:53,721 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-7) Initializing Mojarra 2.1.7-jbossorg-1 (20120227-1401) for context '/WiseBank_EIP_Next'
14:43:58,106 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-7) Error listenerStart
14:43:58,107 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-7) Context [/WiseBank_EIP_Next] startup failed due to previous errors
14:43:58,109 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/WiseBank_EIP_Next]] (MSC service thread 1-7) Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
14:43:58,110 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (MSC service thread 1-7) Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Feb 08 14:43:47 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
14:43:58,112 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (MSC service thread 1-7) Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@9be8ea1: defining beans [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,parentDataSource,accesscontrolDataSource,deshapranDataSource,baltikuriDataSource,dhananjayDataSource,kalyanpurDataSource,joykrishanDataSource,sultanDataSource,imphalDataSource,chaipatDataSource,manderDataSource,chakdwipaDataSource,dongabhangaDataSource,adampurDataSource,palaspaiDataSource,kakhuriaDataSource,pfmsProcessorYesb,dataSource,jdbcDao,entityManagerFactory,transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,customer,wrapMessageFile,rtgsDao,filePollingBean,filePollingBeanYesb,infilePollingBean,fileProcessor,fileProcessorYesb,fileProcessorICI,fileProcessorHDFC,fileProcessorCoopYesb,inwardProcessor,inwardProcessorYesb,inwardProcessorICI,inwardProcessorHDFC,inwardProcessorCoopYesb,myFilter,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,wbRtgsNeftAuthController,databaseDAO,rtgsNeftDao,actionRoutes,template,consumerTemplate,camel-1:beanPostProcessor,camel-1,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
14:43:58,125 INFO  [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] (MSC service thread 1-7) Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'DES'
14:43:58,135 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./WiseBank_EIP_Next: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./WiseBank_EIP_Next: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:95)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
```

Comment: Can you provide the part of your applicationContext file where you are declaring the bean with name 'myFilter'

Comment: Yeah.. sure. i am editing my post.

Comment: Mhh it seems that spring cant find your been. Is this bean part of your war package?

Comment: yes you are right..i find the missing jar for spring. But still i am getting error.I think its beacause of camel. Please check the error console

Comment: I'm not sure but it could be that the from uri in your route3 isn't working as you expect. It seems that camel doesnt get the right filter by this url parameter `filter=#myFilter;delete=true"`. The log says `No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileFilter with value #myFilter;delete=true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `filter=#myFilter;delete=true` to `filter=#myFilter&amp;delete=true`
As it is now camel interprets it as if your filter reference is named "myFilter;delete=true".